# Combine 2 LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to join 2 **LINQ** queries. But I am not getting result according to my desire.

```
List<TeacherSubjectVM> query = (from t in uow.staffs
                                join ts in uow.teachersubjects on t.ID equals ts.teacherID
                                join s in uow.subjects on ts.subjectID equals s.ID
                                select new TeacherSubjectVM
                                {
                                    subjectName = s.Name,
                                    teacherName = t.fname,
                                }).ToList();

List<TeacherSubjectVM> query1 = (from t in uow.subjects
                                 join ts in uow.classsubjects on t.ID equals ts.subjectID
                                 join s in uow.jamats on ts.subjectID equals s.ID
                                 select new TeacherSubjectVM
                                 {
                                     section = s.section,
                                     className = s.name,
                                 }).ToList();

List<TeacherSubjectVM> combine = query.Concat(query1).ToList();
```

Class name and section should be in the same row of subject name and teacher name:

[image]

Comment: You need to make a single query joining all the tables not two separate queries that each have only part of the information. It's doing exactly what you told it to do: concat two lists each of which only has two fields.

Answer (score 1):

Simply join all the tables you want to join in a single step:

```
List<TeacherSubjectVM> query = (from t in uow.staffs
                            join ts in uow.teachersubjects on t.ID equals ts.teacherID
                            join s in uow.subjects on ts.subjectID equals s.ID
                            join cs in uow.classsubjects on ts.subjectID equals cs.ID
                            join j in uow.jamats on ts.subjectID equals j.ID
                            select new TeacherSubjectVM
                            {
                                subjectName = s.Name,
                                teacherName = t.fname,
                                section = cs.section,
                                className = j.name,
                             }).ToList();
```

*I think that's what you are trying to do but your inconsistent variable naming and reuse of variable names makes it really hard to read.*

Comment: @Umair , I think this is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking will not give the desired because the `Concat` function will not merge the objects, it will only append all items of the `query1` to `query` in a new list, here `combine`.

The of reaching your desire is to loop through them and manually merge objects, something like the following:

```
List<TeacherSubjectVM> query = (from t in uow.staffs
                                join ts in uow.teachersubjects on t.ID equals ts.teacherID
                                join s in uow.subjects on ts.subjectID equals s.ID
                                select new TeacherSubjectVM
                                {
                                    Id = ts.subjectID,
                                    subjectName = s.Name,
                                    teacherName = t.fname,
                                }).ToList();

List<TeacherSubjectVM> query1 = (from t in uow.subjects
                                 join ts in uow.classsubjects on t.ID equals ts.subjectID
                                 join s in uow.jamats on ts.subjectID equals s.ID
                                 select new TeacherSubjectVM
                                 {
                                     Id = ts.subjectID,
                                     section = s.section,
                                     className = s.name,
                                 }).ToList();

query.ForEach(item => {
    var otherItem = query1.Where(itm => itm.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    item.subjectName = otherItem?.subjectName;
    item.teacherName = otherItem?.teacherName;
});
```

Note that I added the `Id` property to the `TeacherSubjectVM` class so that the merge can be done regarding it, it should be filled with the subject id since it is the only common thing between the two objects.

*PS: It is always a better practice to use descriptive variable names, that will help enhancing the readability and maintainability of your code :)*